# Docker: How to keep consistent versions of softwares

Tags: docker

I am using a python based image and generally I do the below

```
FROM python:3.10.10-buster

###########################################
# Upgrade the packages
###########################################
# Download latest listing of available packages:
RUN apt-get -y update
# Upgrade already installed packages:
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
```

I am installing a package

```
RUN apt install s3fs
```

I am worried by doing the below a newer version of s3fs will get installed every time i build the image

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
```

How can i pin s3fs to a particular version in my docker image

because recently we had a docker image which i 2yrs old and the s3fs package at that time and now have different versions. And in the recent version the s3fs package is not working as intended as it was working with old version.

So how to pip the versions

Comment: `RUN apt install s3fs=<version>` will install exact version of `s3fs`.

Comment: That would get overridden if OP runs `apt-get upgrade`, no?

Comment: See [How to install specific Ubuntu deb packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-deb-packages-with-exact-version) on [ubuntu.se].  This is trickier than it sounds since the package repositories normally only contain the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main options for you:

1. You pin directly to a version in the `apt` command. This can be achieved by adding a file locally, that you then copy into the container. The file will look like this:

```bash
Package: s3fs
Pin: version 2.1.1*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

You need to adjust to the version that you want.

Then modify your dockerfile like follows:

```
FROM python:3.10.10-buster

# Install s3fs
RUN apt install s3fs=<your version>

# copy the file you created
COPY pinningfile /etc/apt/preferences.d/s3fs

###########################################
# Upgrade the packages
###########################################
# Download latest listing of available packages:
RUN apt-get -y update
# Upgrade already installed packages:
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
```

2. You can create a base image yourself. This way you would create a base image with all the packages installed to a specific version and then use that respectively for your software.

You would then have two Dockerfiles:

```
FROM python:3.10.10-buster

###########################################
# Upgrade the packages
###########################################
# Download latest listing of available packages:
RUN apt-get -y update
# Upgrade already installed packages:
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Now install s3fs
RUN apt-get -y install s3fs=<fixed Version>
```

Build the image, tag it and push it:

```
docker build -t my-s3fs-base:latest .`
docker push my-s3fs-base:latest
```

Now you can use that as base image for your software:

```
FROM my-s3fs-base:latest

RUN <do whatever you need>
```

Comment: hi,  i liked the concept of base image. thanks. the other also i will try